# Using external library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, freetds

I am working on my first objective-c program, and would like to include an external library I found.  I'm fairly new to programming and have never really worked with libraries that were not already included.

Do I just drag the folder into Xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag it in to the project and use

```
#import "TheLibrary/somefile.h"
```

in whichever file you need to use it.